# Bootstrap Dropdown Button not displaying V-For Elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuejs3

I have the following Vue.js (3) component, which uses Bootstrap (5):

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-link text-decoration-none text-dark" type="button" id="languageDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      {{ languages[$i18n.locale] }}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown" v-for="(value, key) in languages" v-bind:key="key">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" @click="changeLanguage(key)">{{ value }}</a>
    </div>

    <li v-for="(value, key) in languages" v-bind:key="key">
      {{ key }}: {{ value }}
    </li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LanguageSwitcher",
  data() {
    return { 
      languages: {
        'en': 'English',
        'de': 'Deutsch',
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeLanguage: function(lang){
      this.$i18n.locale = lang;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Without the `v-for` everything works fine. But as soon, as I add it, only the first element of the object `languages` gets rendered.

As you can see, the list is rendered correctly, with both languages.

[image]

Only in the dropdown, "Deutsch" (German) is not rendered.

[image]

Is this a bug with Bootstrap/Vue or am I missing something?

Comment: First, `<li>` elements are only valid children of `<ol>` or `<ul>`. Secondly, you're doing the `v-for` inside the `.dropdown`. You probably meant to do it inside `.dropdown-menu`. I suggest inspecting the HTML output of your code and compare it with the HTML of the [dropdown examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button) featured in Bootstrap documentation. You'll soon understand what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

im able to solve this by moving the v-for syntax to a template

so instead of this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown" v-for="(value, key) in languages" v-bind:key="key">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" @click="changeLanguage(key)">{{ value }}</a>
</div>
```

do this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
  <template v-for="(value, key) in languages" v-bind:key="key">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" @click="changeLanguage(key)">{{ value }}</a>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).